# How to Logout when Token is expired Android LiveData

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am working on one android app And the problem is when a token is expired, then I need to logout the user. Right now I need to check the token expire in all my Fragment. So Is there any way so that I can do this task from centralized locations.

Comment: If your tokan is expired you can change login state and clear all shared preferences data of app because of your token is expired you can not logout from rest api.

Comment: when token expired, need to rice flag on fragment to activity using interface, flag based logout function you can handle easily

Comment: the question is, how you know token is expired?

Comment: My Question was I got 401 http from server after that I need to redirect to login screen

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `retrofit`? If so, you could add a custom `Interceptor`, which intercepts every response and handles `401` by redirecting to login.

You could also define a `SessionHandler`, that requires a `context` and from the `Interceptor` you would call `sessionHandler.onSessionExpired()` for example. Hope you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to use pub/sub pattern for these kind of problems. In general, when you find out that your token has been expired (for example in an interceptor) raise an event (named session expired). Also, there are some consumers (for example a BaseActivity which all other activities extended it) that capture this event and react to it (according to your question, redirect to the LoginActivity). To implement this approach, you can both use some ready solution (like [greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)) or develop it by using LiveData.